# Images are changing in collectionView when i scroll it swift

Tags: xcode, swift

Images are changing in collectionView when I scroll it swift

What can I do when scroll Images are changing?

Data from json:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell: CollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    let mindata = (data[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary)
    cell.NameShow!.text = mindata["name"] as? String
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
    {
        if let url  = NSURL(string: (mindata["img"] as? String)!),
        data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
            {
                cell.img.image = UIImage(data: data)
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Collection views use a reuse identifier like table views which means that cells are reused as the user scrolls down. When you say that the images are changing as you scroll, what do mean? What exactly are you trying to achieve...you don't want the images to change?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 1):

You code is not full, so I can just suggest some hints:

UITableView and UICollectionView both use reuse techniques, which means the cells are reused from the pool once it's created.

Given the issue you are saying, it looks like you don't clean up your cell either bind the image to a specific location.

You can try depending on your needs:

1. subclass UICollectionViewCell, and in `prepareReuse`, you clean up the image, so the cell is cleaned up, you can feed any image you like, if you don't care the order.
2. bind the image with your cell's `indexPath`, which means you create your image array or tag your image with some sort of index.

For example in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    ...
    cell.img.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
    ...
}
```

Comment: how i do this subclass UICollectionViewCell, and in prepareReuse, you clean up the image, so the cell is cleaned up, you can feed any image you like, if you don't care the order. , i edited the code see it the problem when i scroll down and images seems moved another cell and back to cell , what i can to do to fix it

Comment: @osamamakki probably find some iOS tutorials to get started, you are too new to this

Comment: i didnt find any iOS tutorials for my problem can u help me ?